# Significato di "stia" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> «Il carcerato» risposero Sasà e Matafù. Il Mandralisca si girò a guardare. Un'ombra si scorgeva contro il muro tondo, tra le stalle e 
>   i magazzini dov'erano le giare d'olio, i sacconi di frumento e le **stie** di formaggio. Il Mandralisca, incuriosito, si diresse verso quell'uomo.

Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stia)
ho trovato che "stia" significa

> **1.** Gabbia larga e bassa, di legno o di vimini, entro cui si tengono i polli, e altri gallinacei, per allevarli o per trasportarli dall’allevamento al mercato: *levò, a una a una, le povere bestie dalla stia* (Manzoni); anche, termine di raffronto con riferimento a luogo in cui si stia stretti in più persone: *abbiamo viaggiato in un vagone di seconda classe, pigiati come in una stia*. **2.** Nell’uso ant., conservato  in alcune zone dell’Italia settentr., recinto per ricovero di altri animali, anche domestici (per es., in località del Veneto, porcile).

E le definizioni degli altri dizionari che ho consultato sono simili. Non vedo però che ci sia niente che abbia a che vedere con il formaggio. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "stia" nel passaggio sopra citato?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le stie, intese come gabbie, erano utilizzate in passato in campagna per conservare il formaggio da stagionare al riparo da roditori.

Oggi ci sono in commercio i più eleganti e moderni scaffali di stagionatura, come la cosiddetta [moscaiola per formaggio](https://www.bindienzopienza.com/negozio/cesto-regalo/moscaiola-per-formaggio/), che altro non è che una piccola gabbia con pareti in rete a maglie molto strette.